# Trouble installing ruby via rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I installed Ubuntu today for an internship and was setting up my environment, which required the use of ruby. I tried installing it following the documentation but I keep getting stuck on one step. I tried fixing it using

rvmsudo rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
rvm fix-permissions system

But it hasn't worked so far. I've also done this:

rvm group add rvm $USER

as well but still no luck
What should I do now?

[the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3tdq.png)

Comment: You should [contact the RVM experts](https://rvm.io/support).

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar Error. The Below command works for me,

```
rvm autolibs disable
```

Hope this will work for you.